# Can't properly compare 2 values from a form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a simple exercise from an online course, and we were asked to make a simple form in which the user would fill it with 2 numbers and, if the second number were bigger than the first one, the form would be sent, or else an error message would appear. Simple stuff using only `alert` messages.

The problem I'm facing is: I can't convert the values I get from the forms from a string to a number, the variables keep showing up as `NaN` in the console when I try to `parseInt` the `.value` from the form. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Exercício Módulo 07</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Comparador de Números</h1>
    <form id="form-comparador">
        <input id="valor1" type="number" placeholder="Digite o número menor" required />
        <input id="valor2" type="number" placeholder="Digite o número maior" required />
        <button id="botao-enviar" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
    padding: 20% 0;
}

h1,
form {
    margin: auto;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

form input,
form button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

form button {
    background-color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
}

form button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 217, 0);
}
```

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
const formulario = document.getElementById('form-comparador')
var campo1 = document.getElementById('valor1').value
var campo2 = document.getElementById('valor2').value

var campo1number = parseInt(campo1, 10);
var campo2number = parseInt(campo2, 10);

formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (campo2number > campo1number) {
        alert('Formulário enviado com sucesso!');
        campo1.value = ''
        campo2.value = ''
    }
    else {
        alert('ATENÇÃO: O número do segundo campo precisa ser maior.')
    }
})
```

I have no idea why I keep getting `Nan`, if I compare both variables while they're still strings it doesn't properly work with any number higher than 9.

Thank you!

Comment: You’re reading the form values when the page loads, not when the form submits.

Comment: Need to add all the var inside the eventlistener

Comment: @deceze Now that you mentioned it it does make sense why I kept getting `NaN`, as there where no string to `parseInt` at all at that point in the code. Thank you very much, code is working like a charm now!

Comment: Note that we no longer need the 2012-ish era "put the script at the end of your body": just put in the head, and add the [defer](https://caniuse.com/?search=defer) and [async](https://caniuse.com/script-async) attributes to the script tag. The latter so your script loads in parallel with the page, and the former so your scrip doesn't _run_ until the initial DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to `parseInt` inside the function, AFTER the form was already filled, as pointed out by @deceze and @Mehdi.

Comment: That's really a typo / unsignificant issue. The question can be closed as such.